# Understanding perf.map

Tags: java, linux, jvm, perf

I'm aware of the great [async_profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) tool and I use it for profiling my production projects. Here I want to understand about `perf` and how to understand its output.

I'm playing around with perf to sample stack traces. I run the JVM with options `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PreserveFramePointer -XX:+ShowHiddenFrames` to avoid stack trace messing.

I ran it with command `sudo perf record -e cycles -g -p <my_pid>` in order to sample both user an kernel stack traces and compare the resulting percentage. Here is what I got:

[image]

The `start_thread` symbol seems clear to me. They came from the `libjvm.so` and I can make the assumtion that I ran my 3 Worker Thread to do some job and this is exactly what I see here. The hexidecimal numbers seem to be a runtime compiled java-code instructions addresses.

***QUESTION:*** But where did the `perf-27405.map` come from and why it appeared on top.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`perf-<pid>.map` file is a way to provide `perf` with application-specific symbol map.

In your case one of the sampled instruction pointers `0x00000000008e06e0` belongs to `libjvm.so` - perf can easily show this. But the other one `0x00007f557d10c19f` belongs to anonymous memory region not backed by any object file. This is dynamically generated code, and perf cannot tell anything about it unless someone helps. `perf-<pid>.map` file is the interface for the application or the external tools to provide symbol information for dynamically generated code.

[perf-map-agent](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/perf-map-agent) is an example of such tool for Java. It fills `perf-<pid>.map` file with the information about JIT-compiled methods, so that perf can map these addresses to Java method names.

Comment: So it means I guessed wrong. All the instruction pointers under `libjvm.so` is not actually my JITed methods written in java, but the actual runtime code.

Comment: The question is how to make all the `libjvm.so` instructions to be labeled with something that's human readable. Do I have to compile the JVM with debug symbols myself?

Comment: @St.Antario OpenJDK libjvm does not usually have debug symbols included. You may need to install [separate debuginfo package](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48253607/3448419).