# java debug symbols for jeprof

Tags: java, ubuntu, jvm, jemalloc

I'm have generated heap dump as described here

[jemalloc](https://technology.blog.gov.uk/2015/12/11/using-jemalloc-to-get-to-the-bottom-of-a-memory-leak/)
 When I try to use jeprof command to view the symbols I have this 
[missing java debug symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48250864/jvm-findsignal-function-continuously-allocates-native-memory)
problem. jeprof output is below

```
(jeprof) top
Total: 32802320 B
31968984  97.5%  97.5% 31979144  97.5% JVM_FindSignal
  434512   1.3%  98.8%   434640   1.3% Java_java_util_zip_ZipFile_getZipMessage
  229376   0.7%  99.5%   229376   0.7% inflate
   81920   0.2%  99.7%    81920   0.2% std::__throw_system_error
   50176   0.2%  99.9%    50176   0.2% inflateInit2_
   13344   0.0%  99.9%    13344   0.0% _dl_new_object
    6080   0.0%  99.9%     6080   0.0% allocate_dtv
    3616   0.0% 100.0%     3616   0.0% _nl_intern_locale_data
    2752   0.0% 100.0%     2752   0.0% _dl_check_map_versions
    2512   0.0% 100.0%     2512   0.0% __GI___strdup
(jeprof)
```

I checked ubuntu I have

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
```

when I did apt

```
sudo apt install openjdk-8-dbg
```

I got

```
openjdk-8-dbg is already the newest version
```

I already dbg version, but still the symbols are not resolved. Any idea?

Comment: Why do you think the problem is related to debug symbols? Does `jemalloc` show `JVM_FindSignal` or `AsyncGetCallTrace` as in the linked question, or you are concerned by the hex addresses in the output? The latter is the different problem. `jemalloc` just doesn't know how to traverse Java stacks, it cannot show Java methods. In this case [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/) may help, it can profile native allocations related to Java code. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53598622/3448419).

Comment: @apangin Yes I'. getting JVM_FindSignal in the jeprof output. I have updated the question with the output. The debug symbol answer was suggested in that post.

Comment: Can you try profiling `-e malloc` with async-profiler? If it also shows no JVM symbols, this will mean dbg package does not match JDK version. If it shows, the problem is likely to be in jeprof.