# jemalloc generating many files

Tags: memory-leaks, jvm, java-native-interface, centos7, jemalloc

I followed the [jemalloc](https://github.com/jeffgriffith/native-jvm-leaks) instructions and setup the jemalloc on centOS 7. However, soon after setting

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.so
export MALLOC_CONF=prof_leak:true,lg_prof_sample:50,lg_prof_interval:62,prof_final:true
```

environment variables, I could see a lot of jeprof.*.heap files being written to my current directory. I didn't start my jetty server at all, still, so many files are generated. Which process is generating it?

When I tried to start the application as follows

```
$LD_PRELOAD $MALLOC_CONF $JAVA_HOME/java/ Test
```

It resulted in Segmentation fault, but started writing many files continuously.

I tried to open a jeprof.*.heap like this

```
jeprof --show_bytes `which w` jeprof.47757.0.f.heap
top
```

this gave me 0 bytes. Tried to generate gif file even that file was empty.
How can I fix this?

@apangin
After your help and as described in the [JVM_FindSignal function continuously allocates native memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48250864/jvm-findsignal-function-continuously-allocates-native-memory) post

I was able to get the below details

```
Using local file /bin/java.
Using local file jeprof.57473.0.f.heap.
Total: 79372091 B
78084060  98.4%  98.4% 78084060  98.4% je_prof_backtrace
 1288031   1.6% 100.0%  1474342   1.9% Java_java_util_zip_ZipFile_getZipMessage
       0   0.0% 100.0%  6889972   8.7% 0x00007f3d5ebac3e6
       0   0.0% 100.0%   270421   0.3% 0x00007f3d5ebb8a79
       0   0.0% 100.0%   727762   0.9% 0x00007f3d5ebb8a87
       0   0.0% 100.0%   589239   0.7% 0x00007f3d5ebb9ab2
       0   0.0% 100.0%   854269   1.1% 0x00007f3d5ebb9ac0
       0   0.0% 100.0%   270421   0.3% 0x00007f3d5ebb9cb7
       0   0.0% 100.0%   135210   0.2% 0x00007f3d5ebbc5fa
       0   0.0% 100.0%   135210   0.2% 0x00007f3d5ebbc768
       0   0.0% 100.0%   135210   0.2% 0x00007f3d5ee57146
       0   0.0% 100.0%   143743   0.2% 0x00007f3d5ee8bc25
       0   0.0% 100.0%   444413   0.6% 0x00007f3d5ef13945
       0   0.0% 100.0%   136258   0.2% 0x00007f3d5ef764fb
       0   0.0% 100.0%  8463202  10.7% 0x00007f3d5efbdb8a
       0   0.0% 100.0%   143743   0.2% 0x00007f3d5f220c67
       0   0.0% 100.0%   135210   0.2% 0x00007f3d5f3a5c65
       0   0.0% 100.0% 55473738  69.9% AsyncGetCallTrace
       0   0.0% 100.0% 48103708  60.6% JLI_GetStdArgc
       0   0.0% 100.0% 48103708  60.6% JNI_CreateJavaVM
       0   0.0% 100.0% 11897251  15.0% JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs
       0   0.0% 100.0% 11897251  15.0% JVM_DefineClassWithSource
       0   0.0% 100.0%   271469   0.3% JVM_FindClassFromBootLoader
       0   0.0% 100.0%   431486   0.5% JVM_FindClassFromCaller
       0   0.0% 100.0%   131120   0.2% JVM_FindLoadedClass
       0   0.0% 100.0% 76994237  97.0% JVM_FindSignal
       0   0.0% 100.0%   148137   0.2% JVM_GetCPMethodClassNameUTF
       0   0.0% 100.0%   148137   0.2% JVM_GetCPMethodSignatureUTF
       0   0.0% 100.0%   135210   0.2% JVM_GetClassDeclaredFields
       0   0.0% 100.0%   405631   0.5% JVM_GetClassName
       0   0.0% 100.0%   143743   0.2% JVM_IHashCode
       0   0.0% 100.0%   143743   0.2% JVM_MonitorWait
       0   0.0% 100.0%   431486   0.5% JVM_RawMonitorExit
       0   0.0% 100.0%   659324   0.8% JVM_StartThread
       0   0.0% 100.0% 77220036  97.3% JVM_handle_linux_signal
       0   0.0% 100.0% 11897251  15.0% Java_java_lang_ClassLoader_defineClass1
       0   0.0% 100.0%   271469   0.3% Java_java_lang_ClassLoader_findBootstrapClass
       0   0.0% 100.0%   431486   0.5% Java_java_lang_Class_forName0
       0   0.0% 100.0%   592551   0.7% Java_java_util_zip_Inflater_inflateBytes
       0   0.0% 100.0%   134688   0.2% Java_java_util_zip_Inflater_init
       0   0.0% 100.0%  1117359   1.4% Java_java_util_zip_ZipFile_open
       0   0.0% 100.0% 75438262  95.0% SUNWprivate_1.1
       0   0.0% 100.0%   296275   0.4% VerifyClassForMajorVersion
       0   0.0% 100.0%   356982   0.4% ZIP_Open
       0   0.0% 100.0%  1474342   1.9% ZIP_Unlock
       0   0.0% 100.0%   176271   0.2% _GLOBAL__sub_I_eh_alloc.cc
       0   0.0% 100.0%   176271   0.2% _GLOBAL__sub_I_eh_alloc.cc (inline)
       0   0.0% 100.0% 59721527  75.2% __clone
       0   0.0% 100.0%   176271   0.2% __static_initialization_and_destruction_0 (inline)
       0   0.0% 100.0%   176271   0.2% _dl_init_internal
       0   0.0% 100.0%   176271   0.2% _dl_start_user
       0   0.0% 100.0%   131184   0.2% fork1
       0   0.0% 100.0% 78084060  98.4% imalloc (inline)
       0   0.0% 100.0% 78084060  98.4% imalloc_body (inline)
       0   0.0% 100.0%   592551   0.7% inflate
       0   0.0% 100.0%   592551   0.7% inflateBackEnd
       0   0.0% 100.0%   134688   0.2% inflateInit2_
       0   0.0% 100.0% 78084060  98.4% je_malloc_default
       0   0.0% 100.0% 78084060  98.4% prof_alloc_prep (inline)
       0   0.0% 100.0% 59721527  75.2% start_thread
```

But I don't see any my JNI class names from .so file. I could see many memory addresses. Am I missing anything or the symbols are not resolved correctly?

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you export `LD_PRELOAD` environment variable, jemalloc library gets loaded into *every single* process you run, including every bash command.

If you want to apply it only to Java process, use

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libjemalloc.so $JAVA_HOME/bin/java Test
```

i.e. set the variable (without export) right before the java command.

Comment: Ok thanks, this resolved multiple file generation problem, but now getting this error "libjemalloc.so[55499]: segfault at 6546 ip 0000000000006546 sp 00007ffc5a87bcc8 error 14 in libjemalloc.so.2[5619755ea000+b1000]"

Comment: @Raj You are trying to run `libjemalloc.so` shared library as an executable. This is wrong. Unset `LD_PRELOAD` and then run Java command like I've shown above.

Comment: Thanks apangin, I was able to get the trace and have updated it in the original post above. I don't see any of my class names except for some memory addresses